# How to filter data by date and month only in room database and ignoring year

Tags: android, android-room

```
    @Query("Select * From Mstudent where (strftime('%d%m',dob)) = :todayDate order by (strftime('%d%m',dob))")
    List<Mstudent> getStudentByBirthDate(Date todayDate);
```

this is what I have done but this is giving me an error because the query is not right.
can we filter by date and month only and ignoring year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query (in case you use TypeConvertor `Date` to `Long`):

```
@Query("Select * From Mstudent where strftime('%d%m',datetime(dob/1000, 'unixepoch'))= strftime('%d%m',datetime(:todayDate/1000, 'unixepoch')) order by strftime('%d%m',dob)")
List<Mstudent> getStudentByBirthDate(Date todayDate);
```

Comment: yes, I am using TypeConvertor date to long but still this giving me a null object. By the way thanks for your kind attention to my question.

Comment: Well, try to debug query in some way (with some DB Browser or in another way). Anyway to debug queries is a useful skill working with DB. For example you can remove `WHERE`-condition, and check query `Select * From Mstudent, strftime('%d%m',datetime(dob/1000, 'unixepoch')), strftime('%d%m',datetime(:todayDate/1000, 'unixepoch'))`. Two added fields should be strings kind of `2809` (let's say for today). And they should be equal for rows with date you're searching at. And, by the way, you're welcome )

Answer (score 1):

This Query Maybe you are finding

```
"Select * From Mstudent where strftime('%d%m',datetime(dob/1000, 'unixepoch'))= strftime('%d%m',datetime(:todayDate/1000, 'unixepoch'))"
```